# Print specific characters in a list and change some characters in python

Tags: python

I tried to have output like this `s____e` and print first and last letter in the word for make my game easier but I don't know how?
this is my code:

```
word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else word[0]+'_'+word[-1] for letter in word ]
print(lives_visual_dict[lives])
print('Current word: ', ' '.join(word_list))
```

output:

```
Current word:  l_h l_h l_h l_h l_h l_h
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide sample input/output for the task

Comment: That is unclear, do you want to print real first and last and replace the other by a _ ?

Comment: also, what is `used_letters`? it feels like this is for a hangman game or similar, though would help to clarify.

Comment: yes exactly i want have something like "l_ _ _ _h"

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the first letter, then n times `_` then last char

```
def bounds_only(w):
    return w[0] + "_" * len(w[1: -1]) + w[-1]

for word in "elephant", "camera":
    print(word)
    print(bounds_only(word))
```

```
elephant
e______t
camera
c____a
```

Comment: You can simply use `len(w) - 2` instead of making another slice of the string. (Given that len(w) >= 2)

Answer (score 0):

input_text = "test"

len_input_text = len(input_text)

new_str = input_text[0]+"_"*(len_input_text-2)+input_text[-1]
print (new_str)

output : t__t

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all letters that are not in `used_letters` with _, you can write it like this:

```
word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '_' for letter in word ] 
print(lives_visual_dict[lives]) 
print('Current word: ', ' '.join(word_list))
```

If you just want to print first and last letter and _ in between if all letters are not in `used_letters`, you can write it like this:

```
all_used = sum([letter in used_letters for letter in word]) == len(word)
word = word if all_used else word[0] + '_' * (len(word) - 2) + word[-1]
print(lives_visual_dict[lives]) print('Current word: word)
```